# jquery beforeunload messages depending on button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having problem altering jQuerys `beforeunload()` functionality, depending on user actions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        if (billChanged == false) {
            return false;                    
        }
        else if ( savebutton was clicked ) {
            return false;
        }
        else { 
            return "refreshing page without saving, huh? you're a bad boy!";
        }
    }); 
});
```

The issue im having, that i can't come up with a way to check if 'savebutton' was clicked, as typed in `else if` clause in the snippet above.

The form itself is quite complicated, and i'm not able to alter it that much.

Comment: Bind an event to the save button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var not_saved = true;
    $('#saveButtonId').on('click', function() {
        not_saved = false;
    })

    $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
        if (not_saved && billChanged)
            return "refreshing page without saving, huh? you're a bad boy!";
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define a global variable. Change it's value `onclick` of the button, and then check it in your function

```
var clickedButton = false;
```

Then your html

```
<input type="button" .... onclick="clickedButton=true;">
```

and then in your function

```
else if ( clickedButton ) {
  return false;
}
```